# webpack babel build error after cleaning up node_modules folder

Tags: webpack

Running into the following error after clearing out the `node_modules` folder and do a clean `npm build` and running webpack.

Can someone help me to understand the error I am getting? im new to webpack.

following snippet is my `webpack.config`

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/main'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          plugins: [
            ['react-transform', {
              transforms: [
                {
                  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                  imports: ['react'],
                  locals: ['module']
                }, {
                  transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                  imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
                }
              ]
            }]
          ],
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', 'css', 'scss']
  },
};
```

> ERROR in ./app/components/App.js
>   Module build failed: TypeError: /Users/ericlin/projects/360/app/components/App.js: Property id of VariableDeclarator expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "CallExpression"
>       at Object.validate (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:109:13)
>       at Object.validate (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-types/lib/index.js:541:9)
>       at NodePath._replaceWith (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:208:7)
>       at NodePath.replaceWith (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:186:8)
>       at RewireState.Identifier (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-plugin-rewire/lib/babel-plugin-rewire.js:176:10)
>       at NodePath._call (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
>       at NodePath.call (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:106:12)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:167:16)
>       at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:118:19)
>       at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:211:19)
>       at Function.traverse.node (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:161:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:116:19)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:167:16)
>       at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:113:17)
>       at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:209:19)
>       at Function.traverse.node (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:161:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:116:19)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:167:16)
>       at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:113:17)
>       at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:209:19)
>       at Function.traverse.node (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:161:17)
>       at traverse (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:83:12)
>       at NodePath.traverse (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/index.js:147:25)
>       at PluginPass.exit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-plugin-rewire/lib/babel-plugin-rewire.js:199:11)
>       at newFn (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:301:19)
>       at NodePath._call (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
>       at NodePath.call (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:118:8)
>       at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/ericlin/projects/360/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:167:16)
>    @ ./app/routes.js 31:11-38

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation today after doing clean npm install on old project. It seems that `babel-plugin-rewire` is to blame. In my case, I found two solutions.

First solution was to roll back from `babel-plugin-rewire@1.0.0-rc-5` to `1.0.0-rc-4`

I choose the other solution, which might be not applicable in your case. In my `.babelrc` I had `rewire` plugin declared at top level, so I moved it into `test` environment. So my my `.babelrc` changed from

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-class-properties",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "syntax-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "rewire"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-class-properties",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "syntax-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "rewire"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: rolling back to babel-plugin-rewire 1.0.0-rc-4 worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW My issue was a wonky declaration of a React component:

```js
export const Foo = class extends React.Component {...}
```

Changed it to a normal class declaration fixed the issue. I could imagine in your case it was something similar. (The issue for me was also caused by `babel-plugin-rewire` but I didn't want to remove it from the project yet.)

Comment: How were you able to track down your error, @Andrew Smith?

Comment: I just found the components defined like that and changed them. That was a project from many years ago at this point though. I just stopped using rewire, it's better overall to stop fighting JS/TS with something like restructuring code using babel.